# How to fix parent context unavailable when using proxyquire with ES6 import statement?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, proxyquire

I have the following file to test which is the `migration_repository.js`

```js
import {getDatabaseName}  from "./maria_db_connector"

export default class MigrationRepository {
    getExistingVersions() {
        return getDatabaseName();
    }
```

I am trying to mock the following module `maria_db_connector.js`:

```js
export function getDatabaseName() {
    return process.env.KOA_DATASOURCE_DATABASE;
}
```

and the following test file:

```js
import MigrationRepository from './migration_repository.js'
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire';
const proxy = proxyquire.noCallThru(); 

describe('MigrationRepository', function () {

  beforeEach(function () {
    proxy.load('./migration_repository.js', {
      './maria_db_connector.js': {
        getDatabaseName: function () { return "test" },
      }
    })
  });
}
```

However, when I run this test with mocha using the following command `mocha *spec.js`  I see it is failing in proxyquire on the following line in the load function

```js
  return this._withoutCache(this._parent, stubs, request, this._parent.require.bind(this._parent, request))
```

With the error message

> ```
>  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'require')
> ```

For added context I have the following devDependencies

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "proxyquire": "^2.1.3",
    "sinon": "^15.0.2"
  }
```

and I using node v18.15.0

So how do I populate the parent context with ES6 import statements?

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Show the code of `migration_repository.js` and `maria_db_connector.js` file

Comment: Hi @LinDu thanks for the input, made the adjustment/made it more clear.

Comment: @LinDu here is a repro case: https://github.com/springcomp/proxyquire-es6-issue